# What Nvidia Driver do I use for a Geforce 880M GTS?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I have an iMac 9,1

The graphic card is: `GeForce GT 130` based on what I found [here](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-3.06-24-inch-aluminum-early-2009-specs.html).

What Nvidia driver do I use in Ubuntu to support this card?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Whatever works best for you ;-) The choices are in the additional drivers tab in updates.

Comment: Ok, just trying to understand how it works, but I discovered it is a GeForce 8800M GTS.

I think I will be buying a real PC here soon.

Comment: See http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/73221/en-us. Don't download the driver, but use the version nbr to choose the right propriety driver.

Comment: Any ideas why the machine locks up even after using one of the drivers listed in restricted drivers?